# Storybook throwing errors

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, storybook

I've been trying to figure out what's going on without any success. I've tried reinstalling, updated babel, changed scripts (various things I have found in search for solution) and nothing seems to work.

I followed the storybook guide, initially running:

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init
```

then `yarn storybook` and got this error:

```
./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js] 1.41 KiB {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js] 1.41 KiB {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js] 1.41 KiB {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js] 2.41 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.24 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js] 216 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.25 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/defaultParameters.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.26 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.25 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.25 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js] 2.25 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js] 120 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js] 93 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined] 7.68 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    + 411 hidden modules

ERROR in ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\min-indent\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:316:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\strip-indent\index.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\react-docgen\dist\utils\printValue.js:10:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/defaultParameters.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined main[2]

ERROR in ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\min-indent\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:316:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\strip-indent\index.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\react-docgen\dist\utils\printValue.js:10:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/defaultParameters.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined main[10]

ERROR in ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\min-indent\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:316:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\strip-indent\index.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\react-docgen\dist\utils\printValue.js:10:43)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/defaultParameters.js-generated-other-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined main[9]
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
                          Asset      Size               Chunks  Chunk Names
    __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  6.48 KiB  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0  HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    [./node_modules/@storybook/core/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/templates/index.ejs] 2.13 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error log is pointing out that your `min-indent` package may be missing from your `node_modules` folder for whatever reason.

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Avner\Desktop\NewLib\ewlib\node_modules\min-indent\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

I did a quick search on the storybook github issues and this error appears to be solved in at least 3 ways:

### 1) Try reinstalling the package:

```
// w/ npm

npm i min-indent

// w/ yarn 

yarn add min-indent
```

Example solution(s) from github:

- https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13851#issuecomment-776798296
- https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13980

### 2) Double check that the mentioned package is in your `package.json` dependency list.

The particular package may be a dependency of another package declared in your `package.json`. In that case, it does not need to be listed, and you can try step 3.

Example solution(s) from github:

- https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13597#issuecomment-758297144

### 3) Delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, then do a full reinstall of your local packages.

```
npm i
```

Example solution(s) from github:

- https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4764#issuecomment-452747862

  - Note that this answer says to NOT delete your `package-lock.json`, but rather, to try a different uninstall/install sequence. Worth a try.
- https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13203#issuecomment-731697914

---

It looks like there are a few examples in their [github issues](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues) where version updates may result in some package breaks. If the above solutions do not work, perhaps try submitting an issue on their github. It looks like the storybook team is quite responsive and will help you get rolling!